# What is the most accurate rendering of Psalms 11:7

Tags: hebrew, psalms, textual-criticism, historical-interpretation

4 different translations:

> “For the Lord is righteous, He loves righteousness; His countenance
> beholds the upright.” ‭‭Psalms‬ ‭11:7‬ ‭**NKJV**
>
> “Certainly the Lord is just; he rewards godly deeds; the upright will
> experience his favor.” ‭‭Psalms‬ ‭11:7‬ ‭**NET**‬‬
>
> “For the Lord is righteous; he loves righteous deeds; the upright
> shall behold his face.” ‭‭Psalms‬ ‭11:7‬ ‭**NRSV**
>
> “For the Lord is righteous, he loves justice; the upright will see his
> face.” ‭‭Psalms‬ ‭11:7‬ ‭**NIV**‬‬

**Q: Which is the most accurate from Hebrew to English?**

Answer (score 1):

A textual variation is between פָנֵֽימֹו (3rd person masculine plural suffix)
and
פָנָיו
(3rd person masculine singular suffix).  These are translated the same because it references God.  The main variation in translation is how to translate the words in 11:7.

The most straight forward translation is:

```
   For the LORD is righteous; 
     He loves righteous deeds; 
     the upright shall behold His face. 
            (Psalm 11:7, JPS Tanakh)
```

Essentially the same is:

```
  For the LORD is righteous; 
              he loves righteous deeds; 
  the upright shall behold his face. 
                 (Psalm 11:7, ESV)
```

Also:

```
           For the LORD is righteous, He loves righteousness;
     The upright will behold His face.
                          (Psalm 11:7, NASB)
```

The Septuagint (LXX) basically agrees with the above.

> ὅτι δίκαιος κύριος καὶ δικαιοσύνας ἠγάπησεν, εὐθύτητα εἶδεν τὸ πρόσωπον αὐτοῦ.

For the KJV:

```
  For the righteous LORD loveth righteousness;
  His countenance doth behold the upright.
              (Psalm 11:7, KJV)
```

"the righteous LORD" = "the LORD is righteous"  This is just a variation in how to translate and has the same meaning.

The difference in "His countenance doth behold the upright" is KJV switches the subject and object.  פָנֵֽימֹו (his face) is the Hebrew idiom for *his presence*.  Taking it as the subject, as did the KJV, is unusual.  Rather to say this one would expect: עֵ֣ין יְ֭הוָה אֶל־יְרֵאָ֑יו
(in Psalm 33:18, MT) "the eye of the LORD is upon those who fear him."